# How can I authenticate to Watchguard gateway using command line interface?

Tags: authentication

I'm behind a corporate Watchguard gateway and I need to get authenticated through a pc which has only command line interface

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found of doing this on a command-line only machine is to boot the machine off a live CD with a GUI and browser. Once the CD has loaded fire up the browser and authenticate as you would from any other PC (https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4100). Once done shut down the machine and boot as you would normally. The gateway will usually give you 24 hours before needing to re-authenticate.

If you have access to the gateway configuration you can put exceptions in for particular IP addresses and certain groups (depending on the authentication model used).

I remember reading somewhere that Links a command line browser can do this but you need to recompile it in order to get around the SSL warning. I will post the link to the article if I can find it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Curl, Invoke-WebRequest, ... to send de webrequest as your browser would do. I use the scripts below to authenticate on our non-gui servers. It's pretty sad Watchguard does not provide simural sollutions.

In Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Watchguard Login script
echo -----------------------
echo
echo Enter username
read username
echo Enter Password
read -s password
echo
curl -d "fw_username="$username"&fw_password="$password"&fw_domain=yourdomain&submit=Login&action=fw_logon&fw_logon_type=logon&lang=en-US&redirect=https%3A%2F%2FyourfirewallFQDN%3A4100" -X POST https://yourfirewallFQDN:4100/wgcgi.cgi --show-error -v
```

In Powershell:

```
echo 'Watchguard Login Script'
echo '-----------------------'
echo ''
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 # In case of TLS\SSL errors
$username = Read-Host "Enter username"
$password = Read-Host -MaskInput "Enter Password"
echo ''
$body = @{
    fw_username = $username
    fw_password = $password
    fw_domain = "yourdomain"
    submit = "Login"
    action = "fw_logon"
    fw_logon_type = "logon"
    lang = "en-US"
    redirect = "https://yourfirewallFQDN:4100"
}

$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Body $body -Method 'POST' -UseBasicParsing -URI https://yourfirewallFQDN:4100/wgcgi.cgi
```